# Highcharts issue in IE 7 and 8, text not rotating

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, highcharts

I'm having an issue in Highcharts (using latest version 3) where the yAxis titles aren't rotating as they should. In Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and 10, it rotates correctly:

[image: Correct rotation]

However, in IE8 or 7, this is what happens:

[image: Incorrect rotation]

Code for the yAxis:

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Amount',
                        rotation: 270
                    }
                }, { // Secondary yAxis
                    min: 0,
                    opposite: true,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Another yAxis',
                        rotation: -270
                    }
                }],
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked around and not many seem to have this sort of issue, as it rotates and works correctly in IE8/7, the only issue is that the text would look blurry/smudged.

I read it's possibly my IE browser and switching it to document mode 8/7 that may not reflect exactly what it would look like in IE7/8 (using IE10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In native IE8 it looks like properly `http://i41.tinypic.com/993pli.png`

http://jsfiddle.net/cDpDt/

Comment: Alright I just downgraded to IE8 on my computer, checked it out and it seems to rotate correctly. Looks like it is an issue when using IE9 or higher and changing browser mode & document mode to IE8 or lower that causes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, full compatibility report is available here: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility

Comment: @RyanLangman - ah, that explains it; always remember that compatibility mode is not an accurate copy of a real version of IE8. In particular, if you're using IE10, its compatibility mode doesn't support the `filter` styles that older versions of IE use to do stuff like rotation. Lesson learned: Don't use compatibility mode to test your site for compatibility with old IE. Always use a real copy of each IE version.